# ClearCase: How to checkout version that has since been rename'd

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I hijacked version 11 of MyFile.cc and made changes. In the meantime, the MyFile.cc was changed on the trunk and renamed to NewMyFile.cc. I want to branch off the original version that I had hijacked, and then merge back to the trunk. So I created a config spec that selected version 11 of NewMyFile.cc. I verified that the cs selects that version. However, when I attempt to checkout NewMyFile.cc, I get the following error:

```
Created branch "my_branch" from "NewMyFile.cc" version "/main/int_branch/11".
cleartool: Error: Element already has a branch of type "my_branch" ("/main/int_branch/my_branch").
cleartool: Error: Unable to create branch requested by -mkbranch option in config spec.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out "NewMyFile.cc".
```

**Edit:** I should add that there was no my_branch for the element before I attempted the checkout.

Comment: What you're trying to do is have to versions of the same file checked out at the same time, and you can't do that. That's more or less what the error messages are saying.  Are you trying to modify NewMyFile.cc from this?  If so, you probably need to check-in the version you hijacked and edited on its own branch, then merge from that branch back to NewMyFile.cc.  Otherwise (you're not trying to merge back to NewMyFile.cc — so you're probably trying to create a new file), then you'll still do the checkin on its own branch, then edit the directory to create a new file (I think, but be cautious).

Comment: I'm not trying to checkout multiple versions. First I tried to checkout the original hijacked version. That didn't work because apparently because the element had been renamed. So I unhijacked the file with keep. Then I attempted a pure checkout.

Comment: Then you need to remove the `my_branch/0` version of the file.  (Our CC team arranged a trigger to automatically delete `/0` when you cancelled a checkout that created it.)

Comment: I `rmbranch`'d the element, verified the branch was gone, and tried the checkout again. But got the same error. The checkout command itself is creating the branch on the -mkbranch clause of the config spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `mkbranch` command to create the branch that ClearCase refused to create via the `-mkbranch` clause in the config spec. I then loaded the .keep file from the original hijack into the new branch and checkedin the file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create another branch in your config spec:

- NOT `-mkbranch mybranch` (since you already have one, or so ClearCase believes)
- but `-mkbranch mybranch2`

Then, in a separate view referencing only `mybranch`, try to merge `mybranch2` to `mybranch`.